# How do I create a report from datatable and limit each page to show 24 lines of data (multiple pages needed)

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms, report, reporting

I need to report the data from the data-table into an HTML-file that can be viewed in the browser, but then printed by the user (using the browser-print buttons). The report needs to fit on one or more pages with a page-header and a "grid" of rows and a page-footer (page numbers 1 of 8).  When I take the data-table results into a ListView (scrollable) it appears perfectly for viewing.  I have managed to create a second "disk html-file" that gets shown in the browser when user selects the "Print or Save") button.  The layout of the pages are correct and limited to the proper number of lines per page ...HOWEVER... each page contains the same 24 records -- I need to have page 1 show records 1 thru 24 and page two show records 25 thru 48, and so on, etc.  Any suggestions on how to get the records in groups of 24 so that the paging works in code-behind -- not paging by the user.

This WebForms project is under ASP.NET in the VS-2012-EXPRESS version not full VS-Studio.

Any suggestions will be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: First, you don't need to limit yourself to VS-Express since you can get VS Community version now.
Second, for good print layout I would use the Report component (rdlc file) and source that from the same data you are using to create the HTML output. With it you are not just limiting the page by the number of records but by the actual size of the printed text (e.g. if the text in a record is long enough to wrap to a second line the content may need to move to the second page)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I used the SQL Server Data Tools app to create a report from the dataset.  It appears to be going OK and I most of the report done -- but need to hide and show rows at runtime.  Then, I renamed the report.rdl file to report.rdlc and copied it into my VS-express project with a new web page using the report-viewer control.  But this fails (version issue between 2010 and 2012).  I will sort this out. BUT...I am reluctant to change from VS-2012-Express to a new VS-community at this time to determine whether my web-hosting site supports the reporting-tool.

Comment: One of the differences between Express and Community is that Express doesn't include the RDLC design tool. So, although you could add an RDLC file to a website or webapp and have IIS or IIS Express run it, you couldn't alter it. Also, there are several DLL's that support the report viewer that may need to be included in your site's bin folder if they are not already in the GAC (check out http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ca9151/how-to-use-rdlc-local-report-in-Asp-Net/ as an example)

Comment: These reports are not needed to be generated by end-users.  There are a set of stock reports that I, as programmer, will created based on business requirements.  The report(s) would have a set of user-entered options (parameters) that would be passed to he RDLC via server side code and the result would be a viewable page showing the report where the user can "page-next/back", "find/search", "print" and or "save" the report for their own purposes. I am still trying this in VS-2012 Express but if I cannot , I will switch to Community.  Thanks for your expert guidance. :-) John.

Comment: I was referring to you managing the reports in visual studio, not an end-user creating them. As far as parameters go, there are ways to parameterize the RDLC directly (RDLC's have an internal VB dialect you can use) but I have found for myself that creating an ASHX handler that runs the RDLC is easier. In that context you write the server code in the ASHX similarly to how you would for an ASPX version of your report but instead of rendering as HTML you fill a dataset and pass it to the RDLC to render as a PDF (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: Again, thanks for your reply...It seems that you know much more about VS-community than I do.  Can I install VS-community on my local computer and not make use of Azure or team-coding or internet coding? Can I transfer / upgrade the existing VS-2012-Express code into VS-community? (aspx files and aspx.vb files and the artwork from within the aspx files -- user-control code and artwork)? Can I code with .NET 4.5.1 with VS-community?  thx

Comment: Azure, TFS source control, etc. are all optional (I usually use GIT). I would expect your source code to be completely compatible. However, if you are moving from a 2012 version to a 2015 version, it may try to upgrade your solution and/or project files so best to make a copy or your source folders before you use it (in case you want to go back). Also, 2015 VS will maintaining a local config for IIS Express (in .vs folder so it can be included in source control) but that should only affect new projects (old ones will still use central IIS Express configuration under your documents folder)

Comment: Thank you... I mark all of your comments as "the answer".thanks.